# openFileOutput() method vs FileOutputStream() constructor

Tags: java, android

Why in Android one should use `openFileOutput()` method instead of `FileOutputStream()` constructor?

Would the mode type as a second param of openFileOutput() be the only "respectful" reason for all the cases?

```
FileOutputStream fos;
fos = openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the mode type as a second param of openFileOutput() be the only "respectful" reason for all the cases?

Another difference is that `openFileOutputStream` opens / creates a file in the the device's "internal" storage.  By contrast `FileOutputStream` allows use of both internal and external storage.

A third difference is that `openFileOutputStream` writes files in the context of the current application, while `FileOutputStream` can write in any context ... modulo possible permissions issues.

(Both versions can open files in append mode.  That is not a point of difference.)

Reference:

- Android API Guides > [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: can't the constructor of FIleOutputStream also write in internal storage?

Answer (score 2):

`openFileOutput` is specifically used for file writing into internal storage and disallow writing to external storage.
However, `FileOutputStream` allows you to write to both internal and external storage as well. From my experience, you can create a directory with ease using FileOutputStream in internal storage. You can also set a mode using FileOutputStream as the 2nd parameter in one of its [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)).
Example of how you write to internal storage using FileOutputStream in append mode:

```
File filedir  = new File(MyApplication.getAppContext().getDir("DirectoryNameYouWant"));
File filename = new File("FilenameYouWant");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(filedir,filename),true);
```